# How to delete a node/nodes created by a user with rules?

Tags: rules, nodes

How would I delete a users content automatically when a certain rule triggers?

The content is of a certain content type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add an action for "Fetch by Property" > Node
2. Property > Author
3. Value > The user
4. Add a Loop
5. Add an action for "Delete an entity > List Item" inside the Loop (on the right)